# How to calculate the length of a parabolic arc if two end points & angle at both ends are specified?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

First I confess I my mathematics knowledge is not very good. So first can an expert please first confirm if this question is actually solvable? Because elsewhere on net I have read that you actually need to specify 3 points to find the length of a parabolic arc.

[Imagine this is a plane which takes off at an angle of 30 degrees & gradually makes an angle of 60 degrees by the time it is at a distance of 3 km from the point where it left the ground.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES3s4.png)

Comment: Do you really need a parabolic arc? A circular arc is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality we can suppose that the coordinate are chosen in such a way that the parabola has equation $ y=ax^2+bx$. So we have $y'=2ax+b$.

From the condition that the starting angle is $30°$ we have $y'(0)=\tan 30°=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and this gives $b=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Now the problem is to find a point $P=(p,y(p))$ such that the tangent at this point has a slope of $y'(p)=\sqrt{3}=\tan 60°$ and a distance from the origin $PO=3$.
This gives the system
$$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{p^2+\left(ap^2+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}p\right)^2}=3\\
2ap+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\sqrt{3}
\end{cases}
$$

Find $a=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3p}$ from the second equation and substitute in the first equation. With a bit of algebra you can find $p$ and solve the problem.

---

Substituting $a=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3p}$, the first equation gives $p=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{7}} $, so we have $a=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{9}$ and the equation of the parabola is:
$$
y=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{9}x^2 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}x
$$
with derivative:
$$
y'=\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{9}x + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}x
$$

The ''final'' point  have coordinates:
$$
P=(p,y(p))= \left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{7}},\frac{6}{\sqrt{7}} \right)
$$

So the arc length from $O$ to $P$ is given by the integral:

$$
\int_0^p \sqrt{1+[y'(x)]^2}dx= \int_0^p\sqrt{1+(2ax+b)^2}dx
$$

This integral can be evaluated using first the substitution $u=2ax+b$ that gives:
$$
\int \sqrt{1+(2ax+b)^2}dx =\frac{1}{2a}\int\sqrt{1+u^2} du
$$

than (with a bit of work) using the trigonometric substitution $u=\tan v$.

Comment: How does finding the focus length help me find the arc length? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicSegment.html doesn't mention what role 'p' plays in the formula they give for the parabolic segment?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have no prior knowledge of Parabolas. I thought there would be some simple piece of knowledge that I'm missing which will help me solve the question. It's clear now that I need to study Parabolas thoroughly before I can solve this problem.

Comment: In your figure $3$ is the distance from the starting point (the origin), not the arc length.

Comment: I know that. I am confused. Is the 'p' that I found out my required answer?

Comment: No, $p$ is the abscissa of the final point, from which you can find the arc length. I've added to my answer.

Comment: One might also consider doing a *hyperbolic* substitution instead: $u=\sinh v$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I don't know what is the better...

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the parabola is $$y=ax^2+bx$$ and the given conditions allow you to write

$$\begin{cases}y'(0)=b=\tan30°=\dfrac1{\sqrt3},\\y'(x)=2ax+b=\tan60°=\sqrt3,\\x^2+(ax^2+bx)^2=3^2.\end{cases}$$

Then noting that from the second equation $ax=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}$ we have 
$$x^2+\frac{4x^2}3=9$$ and $$x=\sqrt{\frac{27}7}.$$

---

Now the length is given by the integral

$$\int_0^x\sqrt{1+(2ax+b)^2}\,dx=\int\cosh t\frac{\cosh t}{2a}dt=\frac{t+\cosh t\sinh t}{4a}
\\=\left.\frac{\text{arsinh}(2ax+b)+\sqrt{1+(2ax+b)^2}(2ax+b)}{4a}\right|_0^x$$

by setting $2ax+b=\sinh t$.